# Lexicographic ordering of binary data (with non-identical length) in C++

Tags: c++, sorting, comparison

I have two buffers of binary data, which represent SSIDs. SSIDs are not strings and can do things like have a null character in the middle. I'd like to sort a list of SSIDs lexicographically:

```
\0\0\0\0
AccessPointA
AccessPointB
AccessPointB\0
ZZZZ
```

I already have a framework which just requires a `<0, 0, >0` result for the comparison (so if it were a string, it could use `strcmp`).

However, as two SSIDs are not necessarily the same length, I can't use `memcpy` directly, and I don't really want to have to allocate a buffer and pad both out with nulls or something.

Is there an efficient way to compare two arbitrary-length buffers lexicographically?

Comment: [std::lexicographical_compare](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/lexicographical_compare/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
std::sort(std::begin(Container), std::end(Container), [](SSID const& Lhs, SSID const& Rhs){ return std::lexicographical_compare(std::begin(Lhs), std::end(Lhs), std::begin(Rhs), std::end(Rhs)); });
```